# jQuery - hidden input value from select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have something like this:

```
<select class="bla">
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="2">...</option>
</select>

<select class="bla">
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="2">...</option>
</select>

<select class="bla">
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="2">...</option>
</select>

<input class="alloptions" type="hidden" value="">
```

I want the hidden input field value to change every time a different option is selected in each of the select input fields above.
This value would contain the selected options from all input fields separated with commas.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll find it much easier (and quicker to boot) if you used identifiers rather than classes.

Comment: *I want the hidden input field value to change every time a different option is selected in each of the select input fields above.* i don't think you do.  what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: well I need a certain option inside a wordpress widget. the problem is that this option needs to be a array, so I need a input field that simulates the array by taking all select values separated with commas. then in the backend I use explode to create a array from this string.

Comment: @Alex: So the form is actually send to the backend and processed there? Why not just extract the values of the select fields? Like `$config = array($_POST['optionA'], $_POST['optionB'], $_POST['optionC'])` ?

Comment: the wp widget api is a little weird. in the widget instance you're not allowed to access any $_GET or $_POST, instead you get a array with all the fields you added in the form. fields can be numbers, strings, but I don't think they can be arrays (but I'm might be wrong :)...

Comment: @Alex: I am just saying you can take the values of the select fields from this array and create a new array with these values. This should work. Whether the array you get the values from is named `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `$foobar` does not matter. Of course you have to give your form fields proper names ;)

Comment: here's how it looks:

`
 function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
    $instance['blah'] = strip_tags($new_instance['blah']);
    return $instance;
   }

 function form($instance){
   ?>
   <p><input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('blah'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('blah'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['blah']; ?>" />
   </p>
   <?php
 }
`

Comment: And where do you want to use the explode function? Seems that you could access the field names with `$instance['fieldname']`.

Comment: that's in the form. for each array field it will output a select option with values to choose from.

(there's also a link that will add a new select field on click)

Comment: yes, but $instance['fieldname'] won't be a array, no?
because if multiple select fields have the same "name" attribute only the last one will be $instance['fieldname']

Comment: @Alex: I am not sure if WP allows arrays. But you can test it. You are right, if the select elements have the same name, then only the last one will make it. To make PHP treat them as array, you have to append `[]` to the name, i.e. `<select name="option[]"></select><select name="option[]"></select>...` See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php around example 3

Comment: hey, it works! thanks so much!
I only needed to add [] to the select name :)

Comment: @Alex: Great :) Happy further coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('select.bla').change(function() {
    $value = $('select.bla').map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get().join(',');
    $('input.alloptions').val($value);
});
```

Explanation:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) gets fired whenever the value of a select field changes
- With [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) we create an array of the values of the `select` fields and `join` them to a string separated by commas

Comment: Thanks, It helps me a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

[`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

The .serialize() method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as "input", "textarea", and "select" - meaning you could do the following:

```
$('.bla').change(function(){
   var opts = $('select').serialize();
   $('.alloptions').val(opts);
});
```

Each "select" would need a name value and would produce:

selec1=1&select2=2&select3=1

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use Javascript for that?  If you give all three select boxes the same "name" attribute, the values will be sent to the server as a comma-delimited list.

Just make sure that you do a trim of each element when you do a split, as some browsers will put spaces after the commas.